# OrientDB and NodeJS How to connect DB?

Tags: node.js, orientdb

I am new in OrientDB before that i used mongoDB. I want to know that How to create connection with OrientDB.

I used code below but not working like MongoDB. I want also print print my port Number where my app run like : ' Listening on port 6060 '

```
var orientdb = require('orientdb');

var dbConfig = {
   user_name: "root",
   user_password: "root"
};
var serverConfig = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 2480     //server port Number
};

console.log(orientdb)

var server = new orientdb.Server(serverConfig);

var db = new orientdb.Db("remote:localhost/Gunjan", server, dbConfig);  
                       //I also used 'Gunjan' only here.
db.open(function(err) {
   if (err) {
       throw err;
   }
   console.log("Successfully connected to OrientDB");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `orientdb` was forked into [`oriento`](https://github.com/codemix/oriento), which is maintained.

Example:

```
var Oriento = require('oriento');

var server = Oriento({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 2424,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'yourpassword'
});

// List databases
server.list().then(function (dbs) {
  console.log('There are ' + dbs.length + ' databases on the server.');
});
```

Note that you have to have the OrientDB server running on `localhost:2424`.

Comment: I faced these error :     Possibly unhandled OrientDB.ConnectionError [0]: Socket Closed.

Comment: I used wrong Port number 2480. it's 2424 
Can ask me how can i see my server port number ?

Comment: @GunjanPatel Probably that's a configurable field in the configuration.